# how to create two actions on the same Controller for the same jsp page in spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

the problem is that i want to create two actions in a controller for the same jsp page(main.jsp)
  the first action is executed in the moment of redirection  to the main.jsp page, to display the details of a product , and the second is associated to a button.
how to indicate to spring wish method to call ??

Controller :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "pages/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String detailProduct(final Model model, @RequestParam String id) {

    ProductDTO product = productService.getProduct(Long.parseLong(id));
    ProductModel productbean = mapperDozerBean.map(product, ProductModel.class);

    model.addAttribute("detailProduct", productbean);

    return detailView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "pages/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addToCaddy(final Model model, @RequestParam String id,String action) {

    ProductDTO product = productService.getProduct(Long.parseLong(id));

    ...

    return caddyView;
}
```

jsp : main.jsp

```
...
    <div id="description">
            <h1>${detailProduct.name}</h1>
            <strong id="price">
                <span>previously &pound;299.00</span> ${detailProduct.price}dhs
            </strong>    
            <p>${detailProduct.description}</p> 
            <p>
                <button type="submit" name="addToCaddy" onclick="location.href='/main.do?id=${detailProduct.id}?'" class="continue" value="addToCaddy" >Ajouter au panier</button> ...
```

Comment: Controller handler methods have nothing to do with JSPs, they handle requests to URIs.

Comment: Well, imagine you're Spring, and you receive a request with method GET and URL pages/main, which method would you choose to call? If you don't give Spring a way to select one over the other, it won't be able to do it. One of the URLs has to be different, or a param must be passed in one case and not the other, or a header, or something that makes it possible to differentiate the two requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to use always the same URL when issuing requests from a given page.

For example you could define the controllers like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "pages/main/detail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String detailProduct(final Model model, @RequestParam String id) {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "pages/main/addtocaddy", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addToCaddy(final Model model, @RequestParam String id,String action) {
   ...
}
```

And then on the JSP pass in the correct url in the GET request.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, map GET to one method and POST to another.  Here is an example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "pages/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doGet(
    final Model model, 
    @RequestParam final String id)
{
    ... setup for when the page displays
}

@RequestMapping(value = "pages/main", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doPost(
    final Model model, 
    @RequestParam String id,
    @RequestParam String action)
{
    ... Handle the request resulting from the button click (i.e. the post of a form).
}
```